# Python code to make spot order with Kucoin api

Tags: python, api, kucoin

I'm new to apis but I've been trying to write a code to place a spot order for crypto through the kucoin api but I keep getting a status code of 400, "Bad request". I'm not really sure where the problem is from. This is all in python by the way.

```
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), (endpoint + '/' + nonce + payload_json).encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

This is the code for the signature. Not sure if it's accurate or the cause of the problem.

if you need to see my full code, here:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import requests
import time

api_key = '***********'
api_secret = '***-***-***'

#parameters
symbol = 'BTC-USDT'
side = 'buy'
type = 'limit'
size = '0.2'
price = '60000'

endpoint = '/api/v1/orders'
url = 'https://api.kucoin.com' + endpoint
nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
payload = {
    'clientOid': str(int(time.time() * 1000)),
    'side': side,
    'symbol': symbol,
    'type': spot,
    'size': size,
    'price': price,
}
payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
signature = hmac.new(api_secret.encode(), (endpoint + '/' + nonce + payload_json).encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# Send the API request
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'KC-API-SIGNATURE': signature,
    'KC-API-TIMESTAMP': nonce,
    'KC-API-KEY': api_key,
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload_json)
```